# Optimize MySQL Structure and Query

Tags: mysql, database, query-optimization

**Changing Question considerably, orig my fault due to being on VPN and not local network of MySQL server, but issue still remains that this query is too slow.   My full query is now included and I am adding all layouts for joined tables.**

This Query is taking too long, it does return a large dataset, but limiting the dataset doesn't seem to help it. I have tried it with and without the WHERE based on date range.

Its still taking 8 or more seconds to come back. Using LIMIT also doesn't make a difference.

I fear it may be just too many records in each table, in which case my only option would be to create a set of "working" tables containing like the last weeks worth of shipments and then move them over to a set if "history" tables where the queries would all be slow.   Unless someone can find a way to make this faster.
Thank you.

```
SELECT 
  ShipmentHeader.RecNbr,
  ShipmentHeader.Void,
  ShipmentHeader.SONum,
  ShipmentHeader.DateofReq,
  ShipmentHeader.ShipToName,
  ShipmentHeader.ShipToCity,
  ShipmentHeader.ShipToState,
  ShipmentHeader.ShipToZip,
  ShipmentHeader.ShipToCountry,
  Carrier.RecNbr AS CarrierRecNbr,
  CarrierService.RecNbr AS CarrierServiceRecNbr,
  ShipmentLabelsPrintLogView.Users 
FROM
  ShipmentHeader 
  INNER JOIN ShipmentLabels 
    ON ShipmentHeader.RecNbr = ShipmentLabels.HeaderRecNbr 
  LEFT JOIN VendorService 
    ON ShipmentLabels.VendorServiceRecNbr = VendorService.RecNbr 
  LEFT JOIN CarrierService 
    ON VendorService.CarrierServiceRecNbr = CarrierService.RecNbr 
  LEFT JOIN Carrier 
    ON CarrierService.CarrierRecNbr = Carrier.RecNbr 
  LEFT JOIN ShipmentLabelsPrintLogView 
    ON ShipmentLabels.RecNbr = ShipmentLabelsPrintLogView.ShipmentLabelsRecNbr 
ORDER BY  ShipmentHeader.RecNbr DESC
```

Here are the table structures:

```
CREATE TABLE `ShipmentHeader` (
  `RecNbr` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Void` varchar(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `SONum` varchar(7) NOT NULL,
  `User` varchar(6) NOT NULL,
  `DateofReq` datetime NOT NULL,
  `ShipToName` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ShipToAddress1` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ShipToAddress2` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ShipToAddress3` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ShipToCity` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ShipToState` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ShipToZip` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ShipToCountry` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PackageHeaderRecNbr` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `NegotiatedShipmentCharge` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PublishedShipmentCharge` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CustomerShipmentCharge` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `VoidTimeStamp` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `VoidUser` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`RecNbr`),
  KEY `SONum` (`SONum`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=539140 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8



CREATE TABLE `ShipmentLabels` (
  `RecNbr` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Whse` varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `HeaderRecNbr` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `PackageRecNbr` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Carrier` varchar(60) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Service` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Charges` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `RatedCost` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `PublishedRate` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `CustomerCharge` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `Weight` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `LabelFormat` varchar(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `ShipmentID` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `TrackingNumber` varchar(60) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Label` mediumtext NOT NULL COMMENT 'Base64 Encoded',
  `DateofLabel` datetime NOT NULL,
  `LabelSource` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `VendorServiceRecNbr` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`RecNbr`),
  KEY `HeaderRecNbr` (`HeaderRecNbr`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `PackageRecNbr` (`PackageRecNbr`) USING BTREE,
  CONSTRAINT `ShipmentLabels_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`HeaderRecNbr`) REFERENCES `ShipmentHeader` (`RecNbr`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=542542 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `VendorService` (
  `RecNbr` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `CarrierServiceRecNbr` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `VendorRecNbr` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `VendorServiceCode` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `VendorServiceDesc` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PackageType` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LabelServiceCode` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LabelPackageType` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`RecNbr`),
  UNIQUE KEY `Unique` (`CarrierServiceRecNbr`,`VendorRecNbr`,`PackageType`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=196 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

CREATE TABLE `CarrierService` (
  `RecNbr` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `CarrierRecNbr` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CarrierServiceCode` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CarrierServiceDesc` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`RecNbr`),
  UNIQUE KEY `unique` (`CarrierRecNbr`,`CarrierServiceCode`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=127 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

CREATE TABLE `Carrier` (
  `RecNbr` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `CarrierName` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`RecNbr`),
  UNIQUE KEY `unique` (`CarrierName`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

I am joining on this View I created... that seems to be where the issue is... but the Table its based on isn't in the format for data that I need without this view.

```
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`atr`@`%` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `ShipmentLabelsPrintLogView` 
AS 
select `A`.`ShipmentLabelsRecNbr` AS `ShipmentLabelsRecNbr`,
  (
    select group_concat(distinct `ShipmentLabelsPrintLog`.`User` 
      order by `ShipmentLabelsPrintLog`.`User` ASC separator ', ') 
    from `ShipmentLabelsPrintLog` 
    where (`ShipmentLabelsPrintLog`.`ShipmentLabelsRecNbr` = `A`.`ShipmentLabelsRecNbr`)
  ) AS `Users` 
from `ShipmentLabelsPrintLog` `A` 
group by `A`.`ShipmentLabelsRecNbr`
```

The Table the view is based on is here:

```
CREATE TABLE `ShipmentLabelsPrintLog` (
  `RecNbr` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ShipmentLabelsRecNbr` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `User` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `Workstation` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `DateTime` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`RecNbr`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5908 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

Here is the Explain:

```
id  select_type         table                   type    possible_keys  key           key_len  ref                                          rows     Extra                            
1   PRIMARY             ShipmentHeader          index                  PRIMARY       4                                                     1979351                                   
1   PRIMARY             ShipmentLabels          ref     HeaderRecNbr   HeaderRecNbr  4        Shipping.ShipmentHeader.RecNbr               1                                         
1   PRIMARY             VendorService           eq_ref  PRIMARY        PRIMARY       4        Shipping.ShipmentLabels.VendorServiceRecNbr  1        Using where                      
1   PRIMARY             CarrierService          eq_ref  PRIMARY        PRIMARY       4        Shipping.VendorService.CarrierServiceRecNbr  1        Using where                      
1   PRIMARY             Carrier                 eq_ref  PRIMARY        PRIMARY       4        Shipping.CarrierService.CarrierRecNbr        1        Using where; Using index         
1   PRIMARY             <derived2>              ref     key0           key0          5        Shipping.ShipmentLabels.RecNbr               10       Using where                      
2   DERIVED             A                       ALL                                                                                        6576     Using temporary; Using filesort  
3   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  ShipmentLabelsPrintLog  ALL                                                                                        6576     Using where
```

Is there a way to get the same results faster?

Thanks!

Comment: the size of the row in `ShipmentLabels` doesn't appear to be a problem; MySQL is accessing just the `HeaderRecNbr` index, it isn't even looking at data pages in the underlying table.  (we know that because the explain output is showing "Using index", that's the only column from ShipmentLabels that is referenced. Explain output also shows MySQL is avoiding a potentially expensive "Using filesort" operation, satisfying the ORDER BY clause, accessing rows in cluster key order. Looks to me like most of the cost is in the full scan of the `ShipmentHeader` table.

Comment: Thank you for your comments... the ShipmentHeader does have 536K rows, but I did not think that was an issue. I have other tables with 1.2M records responding quicker.  The ShipmentLabels table is very large in size 3.74GB with 598K records and growing.  The ShipmentHeader table is just 59.59MB with its 536K records.

Comment: UGH! my fault here... I was running this query via a VPN connection using Navicat locally on my laptop... when I run the same query onsite where the MySQL server is on the same network its super fast.   Im sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: Are you *really* pulling all those 500K+ records, or is there an additional where clause in your query filtering the records ? 500K records is a huge dataset, presumably it's gigabytes of data traveling over the network. I'd suspect *this* actually takes more time then executing the query proper.

Comment: Yes I am really pulling all those records... yet only displaying about 50 on the screen of a web grid, then paging through them. Its a record of shipment history and we have over half a million packages with about 1K more added daily. I am determining now if perhaps storing the label itself in its own table with a reference to it for printing purposes may be a bit faster.  I think MySQL is copying it into a temporary table since the data is always being added.  Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Since you're only displaying 50 records at the time, it would be better to use the LIMIT and OFFSET clauses to fetch only 50 records at a time, and perhaps add more filters in your user interface. See for example: https://www.guru99.com/limit.html. Since your dataset is growing daily, the response time can only increase over time. Don't fetch the whole database, but small chunks instead and then you can work out an index to optimize the join between the two tables.

Comment: @Anonymous Thank you again for your comments. I have added the limit statement to my query and it takes the same amount of time.  I think the initial dataset is just so large perhaps I can't do any better?     Perhaps I should keep a smaller subset of the data in another set of tables and refer to the large ones as "history" knowing they will take much longer to query.

Comment: Also want to add that if I include something like
 WHERE ShipmentHeader.DateofReq BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND CURDATE()
It still takes the same amount of time even though it returns only about 22k records.

Comment: Even though you reduced the size of the resultset, MySQL still has to do a full table scan to fetch the results unless it can use an index.
And even if you had an index on this field, MySQL would not be able to use it because it would have to evaluate curdate for each record. See for example: https://riptutorial.com/mysql/example/23472/using-an-index-for-a-date-and-time-lookup. The Explain command will tell you if and when an index is being used while processing your query.

Comment: Thank you again... I have updated the question with more details... I think the issue is the View that I am querying... but I need it in order to get the data I need from the PrintLog Table.

Answer (score 1):

`ShipmentLabelsPrintLog` needs `INDEX(ShipmentLabelsRecNbr, User)`

And don't use `LEFT` unless you really need it.  In your situation, it seems to be preventing the Optimizer from *starting* with the dependant subquery.